# How to align image caption of two parallel images?

Tags: graphics, captions, subcaption, parallel, parallel-texts

```
\documentclass[\classfontsize,\papersize,twoside,showtrims,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, subcaption}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graphics/MDOBMEP.png}
\caption{Plot of BMEP and BMEP at the constant speed of 1500 RPM}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graphics/MDOefficiency.png}
\caption{Plot of engine efficiency and break power at the constant speed of 1500 RPM}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

For the above code, image looks likes this: Captions aligned with some indent (That's what I do not need) and proper figure numbers.

[image: With captions aligned with some indent]

When I tried another method with the following code:

```
\documentclass[\classfontsize,\papersize,twoside,showtrims,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, subcaption}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graphics/MDOBMEP.png}
  \caption{Plot of BMEP and BMEP at the constant speed of 1500 RPM}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graphics/MDOefficiency.png}
  \caption{Plot of engine efficiency and break power at the constant speed of 1500 RPM}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Geometrical figures}
\end{figure}
```

The result looks like this: (With proper caption alignment but without sub caption number like Fige. 3.1 and Figure 3.2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Qt9.png))
[image: With proper caption alignment but without sub caption number like Fige. 3.1 and Figure 3.2]

My question is:

How to make a parallel image caption with proper alignment as 2nd example and with figure numbers as like example 1.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Assuming you've loaded the `caption` and `subcaption` packages, please do tell us how (and with which options) these packages were loaded.

Comment: You should post a full code, as the solution may depend  on the document class and loaded packages.

Comment: Here is a info: documentclass is memoir. And caption package is \usepackage{graphicx, caption, subcaption}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

options `\classfontsize` and `\papersize` are not defined in `memoir`. your mwe is not complete and consequently can not be tested. however, the following changes and simplification of your code works fine:

```
\documentclass[twoside,showtrims,extrafontsizes]{memoir} % <---
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}        % <---
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}  % <---
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{graphics/MDOBMEP.png}  
\caption{Plot of BMEP and BMEP at the constant speed of 1500 RPM}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}  % <---
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{graphics/MDOefficiency.png}
\caption{Plot of engine efficiency and break power at the constant speed of 1500 RPM}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]